# After Reconfiguring DNS, ISP's "Enhanced Error Page" Still Shows

Tags: router, dns, dhcp

After I configured my router to use openDNS's nameservers I went to test it out by going to a random website that doesn't exist.

Much to my surprise, my ISP's catch page showed up offering me their "enhanced error result page", which is ISP speak for slimey upsell opportunity.

On my computer I checked my settings (via `ipconfig /all`) and indeed my computer is getting DNS from my router at `192.168.1.1`. So the problem must exist on my router.

I've fired up wireshark to watch DNS requests over the wire coming from my computer, but since my computer is just taking DNS from the router, I'm guessing this will end up not showing me much.

What is happening on the router side that is allowing the ISP to still have their error page show up even though I have setup static DNS under DHCP in my router?

Comment: Is your router really yours or one of ISP box? In the last case they may have access to it. If you configure your router with same nameservers but your computers gets other ones, you have a local configuration problem, or some things that revert your changes. Try first with just DNS queries, and only the browser after.

Comment: If you set your router to send out dhcp with dns servers set to opendns and you still get the router instead doing DNS lookups, then you'll need to statically configure on each machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all your internet traffic goes through your ISP, they are well able to intercept your DNS requests, no matter what your router setting may be. You may have to go to your ISP account page, or send a specific request to some web app provided by your ISP to opt out of their "enhanced" error pages.

Comment: So they are overriding my DNS to serve me these pages?

Comment: @rec yup, though if you're using DHCP to set the DNS,  your DNS settings on your computer are whatever your router has sent you - instead simply change them to manual settings, maybe 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and see if that makes any difference, if it doesn't then it appears your ISP is indeed intercepting your DNS traffic.